# Solutions of a linear diophantine equations satisfying condition

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The problem asks to solve the linear

$$16x - 5y = 2010$$

Reducing modulo $5$, we get $x \equiv 0 \pmod 5 $ so $x= 5k$ for some integer $k$. Plugging back in the equation, we get $y= 16k-402$.

The converse is obvious therefore the couple solutions are $(5k,16k-402)$ where $ k $ is a random integer.

**I'm stuck with the following question** that asks to determine solutions $(x,y)$ satisfying $\gcd(x,y) = 5$.

By necessary condition we surely get $k \equiv 2 \pmod 5$ so $x = 25h + 10$ and $y = 80h - 370$ for some integer $h$.

For these $x$ ad $y$ to be of $\gcd = 5$, we must have $\frac x5$ and $\frac y5$ coprime.

That is $5h+2$ and $16h-74$ coprime.

but this is not always true since for even $h$ we get $x$ and $y$ divisible also by $2$.

Ok, assuming $h = 2z+1$ we must have

$10z+7$ and $32z-58$  coprime.

Again for $z = 3$ we get $10z+7$ and $32z-58$ both divisible by $3$.

To what limit should one continue here ?

Any alternate ways ?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you note, the solutions to the equation are precisely the pairs of the form $(x,y)=(5k,16k-402)$. Then for a solution to satisfy
$$5=\gcd(x,y)=\gcd(5k,16k-402)=\gcd(5k,k-402),$$
you must have $k-402\equiv0\pmod{5}$, or equivalently, $k\equiv2\pmod{5}$, and then
$$(x,y)=(25h+10,80h-370),$$
for some integer $h$. So far so good. Now applying the Euclidean algorithm shows that
\begin{eqnarray*}
\gcd(x,y)&=&\gcd(25h+10,80h-370)\\
&=&5\gcd(5h+2,16h-74)\\
&=&5\gcd(5h+2,h-80)\\
&=&5\gcd(402,h-80),
\end{eqnarray*}
which shows that $\gcd(x,y)=5$ if and only if $h-80$ is coprime to $402=2\times3\times67$.

Comment: Can we rephrase the statement $\gcd(m-80,402)=1$ as " $m-80$ is not divisible by any of the numbers $2$, $3$, $67$ " (prime factors of $402$)

Comment: oops Ive just seen your edit